# Which PHP modules are required to install wordpress?

Tags: php, vps, wordpress, lamp

I have 5 wordpress sites. I use hostgator shared hosting for all of them. Now I have decided to switch on to a VPS.

I got a unmanaged VPS and configuring it for wordpress. I am following this tutorial as suggested by a member from webhostingtalk : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-ubuntu-vps

I am configuring the LAMP stack now. steps are from this page : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

In step 3 , while installing apache it comes to point where I have to select the php modules. I don't know what modules to select. my requirement is 5-6 websites on wordpress.

Kindly tell me which modules to install for wordpess? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I googled and found out this thread : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42098/what-are-php-extensions-and-libraries-wp-needs-and-or-uses

The 4th answer with 2 votes have this list :

```
php5-cli
php5-dev
php5-fpm
php5-cgi
php5-mysql
php5-xmlrpc
php5-curl
php5-gd
php-apc (not required, but recommended)
php-pear
php5-imap
php5-mcrypt
php5-pspell
```

Is it good enough?

Answer (score 1):

The standard PHP configuration is enough. I'm doing ok (Debian) with `php5-common`, `php5-mysql`, `php5-cli`... This is documented on the Internet but I would try installing just `php5` and `php5-mysql`.

Comment: php5-cgi or php5-common?

Comment: I have no php5-cgi and wordpress works ok (my mileage) since aeons.

Comment: I insist that this is heavily documented on the Internet. However am too lazy at this moment to find you a link.

Comment: I edited the question and added the link. Kindly check is it good enough.

Comment: If you are using virtual machines (and maybe even not using) though not a completely safe and _industrial standards clean and compliant_ approach, sometimes installing just what the system is _asking for_ is a practical GTD policy.

Comment: I installed php5-gd and everything is fine.